# Pin from app to start

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have a LongListSelector with items. I made a contextMenu, so when you hold an item for some time you get an option to "pin to start". I didn't have a problem with binding the right item "name" and tile picture, but I have a problem with opening the right item than (or opening in general).

This is the code to pin the item to start:

```
        private void Pin_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["country"] = countriesList.SelectedItem;
        Country selectedCountry = (sender as MenuItem).DataContext as Country;

        string page = "/countryPage.xaml?id=" + countriesList.SelectedItem;

        StandardTileData tileInfo = new StandardTileData
        {
            BackgroundImage = new Uri(selectedCountry.Flag, UriKind.Relative),
            Title = selectedCountry.Name
        };
        ShellTile.Create(new Uri(page, UriKind.Relative), tileInfo);
    }
```

The problem is on the countryPage, because there is no data context and the app crashes:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var k = (app.MainPage.Country)PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["country"];
    DataContext = k;
}
```

Comment: Have you added the data for `PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["country"]` before pinning?

Comment: If you're opening a "country" page, it's unwise to couple that to the `MainPage`.

Comment: @PeterRitchie Yes, I have updated the upper code, I tried like that later, doesn't work. What do you mean unwise, why ? What should I do different ?

Comment: Unwise that in the case of a pinning a page, you're pinning to a particular deep page--I doubt the framework will create the MainPage before going to your country page.

Comment: What do you trying to set here? `DataContext = k;
}`

Comment: One line before that is var k = ..

Answer (score 0):

2 suggestions based on your code :

Is the itemSource for your LongListSelector a collection of Country objects ? Because on the second page, you are trying to typecast the state data into a country object. That might be a problem.

Secondly, try using IsolatedStorage instead of Phone State, as State is transient data, as in not guarrenteed to last forever.

Comment: I figured that I must use IsolatedStorage, but I don't have any experience with it.

Comment: Since you are storing only city names, which won't be very long, you can use IsolatedStorageSettings instead of IsolatedStorageFile. For detailed implementation, check this [link](http://jeffblankenburg.com/2010/10/15/31-days-of-windows-phone-day-15-isolated-storage/)

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you have a list of `Country` objects somewhere that you are using to populate the `ItemsSource` of your `countriesList` `LongListSelector`.  Why don't you keep that list defined publicly in your **App.xaml.cs** class and make sure it is populated when the application is started using `Application_Launching()`.

```
public static List<Country> Countries { get; set; }
```

In your `Country` objects, define some kind of unique identifier property using something like a `Guid`.

```
Guid m_CountryID;
public Guid CountryID
{
    get { return m_CountryID; }
    set { m_CountryID = value; }
}
```

Populate it when you create your `Country` objects

```
Country.CountryID = new Guid()
```

In your `Pin_click` method, set the QueryString id parameter to your `CountryID` from above.

```
string page = "/countryPage.xaml?id=" + selectedCountry.CountryID.ToString();
```

Then, in the `OnNavigatedTo` method of your **countryPage.xaml.cs** pull the `Guid` from the id parameter of your QueryString to retrieve the given `Country` object.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    string countryID = string.Empty;
    NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("id", out countryID);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Concat("URI: ", e.Uri.ToString(), " | CountryID: ", countryID));

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(countryID))
    {
        Guid countryGuid = new Guid();
        Guid.TryParse(countryID, out countryGuid);

        Country country = App.Countries.Where(x => x.CountryID == countryGuid).Select(x => x).FirstOrDefault();
        if (country != null)
        {
            // ***** BUILD YOUR PAGE AS NEEDED HERE *****
            // TextBlock1.Text = country.Name; 
        }
    }
}
```

Now that you have the chosen `Country` object, just build that page as you see fit using the information in it.

Of course, all of this presumes you are maintaining the state of your country list between application sessions.  Typically you would just write the list to an XML file in your isolated storage.  GeekChamp has a great list of articles to get you up and running with isolated storage. 
http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/all-about-wp7-isolated-storage---read-and-save-xml-files

Although, you could do this without worrying about isolated storage.  Just use fixed `Guid` values (`not new Guid()`) when creating the `Country` objects in your `Countries` list, or choose an integer type and always ensure that the same integer value is associated with each `Country` as you rebuild it each time the app starts.